# Can I paint the cement under the fireplace hearth?

Tags: painting, fireplace, hearth

I recently had a fireplace installed. The floor wasn't level so there is a wedge of cement exposed below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
<sup>*Click for larger view*</sup>

The installer says I should conceal it with wooden beading but personally I hate the stuff, so I was wondering if I could just paint the cement? 
Would I need to prepare it with something to stop it cracking first?
What paint would I use?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can paint it.

Personally, I always use oil-based paints because they last longer, but you can use whatever paint you want (water colors?)

Concrete is porous so you might want to use a grain filler or sealer of some kind before painting.

There are thick paints specifically designed for painting concrete, but they tend to look pretty industrial.

Comment: What do you mean by a grain filler?

Comment: There is this stuff you can fill in the grains of wood with to make it non-porous. It probably works on concrete too. For example, look up "Old Masters Woodgrain Filler" on Amazon. Note that it takes some skill to use this stuff. You want to practice on small areas until you have some experience with it.